# Purchasing an artwork for commercial use

Tags: contract-law, licensing

I am in the progress of purchasing an artwork I would like to use on my webpage and as a logo for the software I am developing. I found an artist who promoted his art on his webpage and we agreed on a price, but he doesn't have any contract template.

Does anyone know where I might get a template both parties sign so I can legally proof I bought the artwork and can use it everywhere in my app and website?

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's easy to Google legal templates.

Comment: Sure, feel free

Comment: But its not easy to google them. Some of them are unnecessary long, so thats why I asked on this forum, not bc I dont google before

Comment: @BlueDogRanch look at the Inakis answer and remember next time to prematurely vote for closing, seems googling just a plain template isn't that simple..

Comment: And if you actually *read* Viggers answer, you'll note that it's foolish for a novice - like you - to use a template, because you don't know what you're doing in a legal sense, and you will shoot yourself in the foot and cost yourself a lot of money. And, notice that it takes more than one vote to close a question; so you need to read the help are of SE. So please, **read** before you comment. Or ask a question.

Comment: But thats the whole point. What you just described would have been a proper answer, just saying. I leave this link here for you https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/. Thanks for your last comment, that helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know where I might get a template both parties sign so I can legally proof I bought the artwork and can use it everywhere in my app and website?

I personally don't. However, templates are unlikely to fit one's particular legal needs. Also, it would be a mistake to presume that templates confer or strengthen the enforceability and binding nature of a contract.

From a legal standpoint, the focus should be on ensuring that the *terms* of your contract reflect the parties' rights and obligations. A template could even be detrimental in this regard, since it could inadvertently lead the novice draftsman to omit crucial terms & conditions just for the sake of sticking to whatever generic format he downloaded.

Comment: @DanielStephens Glad it helped. The [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) might be of your interest. This resource outlines the principles of contract law and is frequently cited by courts in the US when deciding contract disputes.